# Overlapping bar charts where stacks start from y axis

Tags: dc.js

Is it possible, using dc.js, to construct a bar chart where the stacks are not placed on top of each other? Currently, my code produces charts that look like this:

[image]

Instead I'd like each of the stack bars to start from y axis and not from the value where the previous stack value ends. This may/will lead to the bars overlapping, so perhaps adding transparency will help here. A simple css rule will probably work here:

```
 .dc-chart rect.bar { opacity: 0.75; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely want to build a composite chart that includes a bar chart for each category.

You can build a group for each color in your chart like this:

```
        usaGroup = categoryDimension.group().reduceSum(dc.pluck('usa')),
        russiaGroup = categoryDimension.group().reduceSum(dc.pluck('russia'));
```

Here is a jsFiddle to demsonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/nK6K7/

```
composite
    .width(400)
    .height(300)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain([1,2,3]))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .yAxisLabel("User Count")
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .compose([
        dc.barChart(composite)
        .centerBar(true)
        .gap(100)
        .colors('red')
        .dimension(categoryDimension)
        .group(russiaGroup),
        dc.barChart(composite)
        .centerBar(true)
        .gap(100)
        .colors('blue')
        .dimension(categoryDimension)
        .group(usaGroup)])
    .brushOn(false)
    .render();
```

You'll need to play around with the styling... the blue and red combine into a purple color when the opacity is lowered.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for: I overlooked the part about the composite charts on the docs.